# Converting Balanced Audio to Unbalanced Audio without Damaging Sink

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, audio, differential, circuit-protection

I want to receive a stereo balanced audio signal and feed it into the stereo microphone inputs via my motherboard's header pins.

[image]

I added about a 30 dB reduction in gain which looks good on the scope and audio sounds great from headphones/speakers.

But here is my issue:

If the opamp is not powered, I will be sending the hot signal into my L/R mic inputs without gain reduction and I am afraid that will cause damage to the motherboard. So I need to attenuate or mute the signal if no power is applied.

My two ideas are:

1. Use a JFET to mute the circuit like shown here: https://sound-au.com/articles/muting.html#s2

or

2. Use a unity gained design for the differential amplifier then just have a voltage divider at the input of my circuit to reduce the level.

My question is: Do you see issues with these approaches and is there an alternative approach you would suggest?

[edit]

Here is my modified circuit where I removed the regulator and just use the output from the 7660 charge pump. I also added parallel JFET's with gates tied to -5v rail so they will attenuate any signal headed to the sink when there is no power applied to the opamp:

[image]

Comment: I'd go for JFET.

Comment: I'd go for 2 because it's easier and is clearly going to work. Having only a -5 volt rail to turn off the JFETs may not work.

Comment: I vote for 2, for simplicity.

Comment: Am concerned with the -5V DC supply: doesn't that 7660 put out -5V on pin 5? The 7905 regulator that follows requires at least -7V on its input pin. Do you *really have* a regulated -5VDC at 7905 output pin?

Comment: @glen_geek good spot.

Comment: You could just use a couple of small audio transformers. I very much doubt you'd damage the mic inputs on your motherboard anyway.

Comment: Could you put the attenuation after the opamps?  I'd think that would be better as far as noise is concerned, but then the opamp output has to swing the full input voltage, so that may be a problem.

Comment: @glen_geek Thank you for the catch - since my output is less than 2 Vpp I was more concerned about reducing noise than coming too close to the negative rail. I noticed the 7660 has a built in regulator, do you think I can just remove the 7905 section?

Comment: @physiii *power supply rejection ratio* of LM358 for -ve supply is poor @ 10kHz where 7660 oscillates. (-45dB). I still *would suggest* trying 7660 direct...as a precaution, I'd send audio to SpectrumLab to look for 7660 10kHz-20kHz injection. Personally, I'd not hear anything that high-frequency, but **you** might. As-is, I'd bet negative-going peaks are likely clipped.

Comment: @glen_geek Good idea about using SpectrumLab. Can you checkout my modified circuit? I removed the regulator and added jfet's for attenuating when there isn't power.